# How to correct the exception: could not be parsed at index 0 in a conversion from string to OffsetDateTime?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date

I am trying to insert a date in the Oracle database using Spring Boot, I have a date as String in "20200723" format, then I try to convert it but when I try to convert to the entity that has a field type OffsetDateTime with a mapped it jumps an exception Text '20200723T00: 00: 00.00' could not be parsed at index 0. Thank you very much for your help.

Entity

```
      @Column(name = "of_date")
      private OffsetDateTime ofDate;
```

Mapper and method

```
        @Mapping(target = "ofDate", source = "kDto", qualifiedByName = 
        "ofDate")
        InTemp toEntity(KDto kDto);

        @Named("ofDate")
        default OffsetDateTime mapPostedDate(KDto kDto){
        LocalDateTime activationDate = LocalDateTime.parse(kDto.getOfDate() + 
        DEFAULT_TIME);
        return activationDate.atOffset(ZONE_OFF_SET_ACTIVATION_DATE);
```

Comment: Instead of **OffsetDateTime** do you not want **ZonedDateTime** (the realistic time at some spot on the world)? Then there is the problem with Date versus DateTime leading to the mentioned error. Certainly someone will answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add and parse the time part:

```java
@Named("ofDate")
default OffsetDateTime mapPostedDate(KDto kDto) {
    return OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse(kDto.getOfDate()),
                             LocalTime.MIDNIGHT,
                             ZONE_OFF_SET_ACTIVATION_DATE);
}
```

Comment: I made the changes this way and it still keeps showing me the same exception

Comment: @Jhon It says `'20200723T00: 00: 00.00' could not be parsed` even though you no longer append the default time text to the input? That doesn't sound right, now does it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a DateTimeFormatter and use it as your string is not the default

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HH: mm: ss.SS");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

Comment: I made the changes this way and it still keeps showing me the same exception